# How to use Moment.js Timezone with a timezone code?

Tags: jquery, momentjs

In the [Moment Timezone documentation](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/), it states that a date/time can be created via a timezone name, like so:

```
moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").format();
```

But how can I create a date/time with a timezone code?

I have tried this, but had no luck:

```
moment().tz("GMT+8:00").format();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use "Etc/GMT+8". You can use the data builder to build the data: http://momentjs.com/timezone/data/

```
moment().tz("Etc/GMT+8").format();
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Although, does that mean that Moment.js does not accept time zones such as `GMT+5:30`?

Comment: I think that was wrong. It works when I use moment().zone("+05:30").format(): http://jsfiddle.net/Vn5PH/2/